# changing desktop background in windows 10 via python

Tags: windows, python-3.x, windows-10

I'm working on a small project for myself and I hit a wall. I need to change the desktop background on Windows 10 64-bit. I have attempted to use the script below to change the background based on a local image. The code executes without errors, however the desktop just turns black. I double checked and my image is at `c:\CuratedWallpaper\Mario.bmp` so that is not the issue.

```
import ctypes

directory = "c:\CuratedWallpaper"
imagePath = directory + "\Mario.bmp"

def changeBG(imagePath):
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, imagePath , 0)
    return;

changeBG(imagePath)
```

Answer (score 7):

I use SystemParametersInfoW instead of SystemParametersInfoA like this:

`ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 3)`

It is a matter of ANSI vs UNICODE path string.

It works for me in windows 10.

Comment: Can you explain the last parameter you're using?

Comment: The command "SystemParametersInfo (20, 0, path, 3)", fails when executed as a script without interaction, using this code (https://www.coder.work/article/981614), it generates the error 1459 (ERROR_REQUIRES_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWSTATION according to the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699- ); in my case, create a link to a batch file that executes the script of python which install in "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData \Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

Comment: @finngu, the `3` seems to be `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE`. The first constant “writes the new system-wide parameter setting to the user profile.” The second one “broadcasts the `WM_SETTING­CHANGE` message after updating the user profile.” https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160721-00/?p=93925

Comment: @StSav012 Thank you for the additional information!